# Authentication class not working with Traits in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing a few problems while working with `Traits` and `Authentication` in laravel. This is my code:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait Multitenantable {

    protected static function bootMultitenantable()
    {
        dd(\Auth::user()->name);
        if (auth()->check()) {
            static::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->user_id = auth()->id();
            });

            static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {
                $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id());
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And the result taken in my screen displayed:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

I think `Auth` class does not exist while I use it in `Traits` and they are not working although they are even working other classes except for `Traits`.

I don't know how to resolve problem, help me!

Comment: The problem is, there is no authorized user at the time the bootMultitenantable() is called

Answer (score 2):

Maybe at the time the model is booted the **session** is not yet started then `auth()-user()` is null, you could try this code instead, or something like:

```php
protected static function bootMultitenantable()
{
    static::creating(function ($model)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $model->user_id = auth()->id();
        }
    });

    static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            $builder->where('user_id', auth()->id());
        }
    });
}
```

The basic idea is to put `auth()->check` inside the callback closure that is called only when the event runs or the scope is applied. You should have the *session started* for that time, almost for the `creating` event.

Comment: Thank you so much. After striving for hours, your solution worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)